# Should I access the database multiple times or loop through an array?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, optimization

Which is the most efficient method for gathering related data?

Lets say we have multiple projects that are associated to one category 1:M.

Each project holds the ID value of the Category it is a part of. I have an array object of all my projects, I now want to add to that array object its category name rather than its ID.

So for example instead of:

project_id: 1
project_title: first project
project_desc: bla bla
project_category_id: 1

I want it to be:

project_id: 1
project_title: first project
project_desc: bla bla
project_category: first category

I'm not having trouble achieving this, I'm curious what the most efficient way to achieve it is.

**Option 1**

```
$projects = $this->projects_model->find_all();
$categories = $this->category_model->find_all();

foreach($projects as $project){
   foreach($categories as $category){
      if($project->category_id == $category->id){
         $project->category = $category;
      }
   }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
$projects = $this->projects_model->find_all();

 foreach($projects as $project){
   $project->category = $this->category_model->find_by('id', $project->category_id);
 }
```

It's likely there are many other methods for achieving my desired result and potentially in a more efficient manor, if that's the case I'd love to learn.

Comment: why not use SQL for this? i am assuming you have some sort of database so all you need is "select * from projects where category_id = '$category'

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have used my prebuilt db helper method in my examples. Those find_all methods essentially do 'select * from projects'

Answer (score 1):

1. You should profile this yourself and you'll have your answer
2. Hitting the database is expensive. Accessing arrays data is not. This means you'll want to hit the database as few times as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your find_all and find_by functions request data from a database, option 1 will be preferable until the ratio between categories sought and categories used becomes low. Sequential (i.e. read-then-read-the-next-row) read operations on SQL are much quicker than targetted read operations.

Ultimately, though, if I were you, I would worry less over the actual array looping and more about how you acquire your data, as *this* is where the performance drain will be.